# (ie10,ie11) error in select tag (use multiple)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

first, i'm not very well english. sorry.

i want option text dynamic change in `<select multiple>`.

so, i use javascript..

```
options[].text = 'changeValue';
```

value change is success,
but I can not select another option anymore.

can select other option in ie9
but ie10 and ie11 can not select other option.

please let me know why this happen.

html source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <select multiple onchange="myFunction(this)">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option>Pineapple</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction(selTag){
        var x = selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
        selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text = "value";
        //selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].innerHTML = "value";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You selected: " + x;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

capture screen is

http://youtube.com/watch?v=qfWnvkpY1J0&feature=youtu.be

---

my os is

windows 7 x64 ie9,
vm windows 7 x86 ie10,
vm windows 7 x64 ie11.

Comment: That's what the code does, when you select something, it sets the options text to "value", what are you expecting ?

Comment: watch capture screen please. code is not important. I want to do with the mouse to select other options in ie10,ie11.

Comment: You should rather make a jsfiddle.net example than showing us videos.

Comment: jsfiddle :  http://fiddle.jshell.net/8tF47/
please check this in ie10 or ie11.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I changed from using .text to .innerHTML.

Change your code to:

```
    selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].innerHTML = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run thru the entire options, and see if `selected` property is setted.
Change your script to the following

```
<script>
function myFunction(selTag) {
    var x = [];
    for (var i=0; i<selTag.length; i++) {
        if (selTag[i].selected)
            x.push(selTag[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You selected: " + x.join();
}
</script>
```